# ADFS as the Relying Party

Tags: adfs, adfs2.0

I'm trying to set-up ADFS as a relying party, and I've read several tutorials which requires me to install ADDS first before I can configure ADFS.

Question: Is it possible to configure ADFS as a relying partner without utilizing ADDS? The user info will be validated from an SQL server instead and not from ADDS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this link:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758187%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

> Claims-aware applications do not require a local user store. All information about a given identity is contained in the token that is presented by the application. The application may store additional information that links to the identity that is presented in the token, but a user account in Active Directory is not required.

I think this answers my question.